# Backbone.js save "states"? (Caching Strategy)

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I saw this simple caching strategy:

```
// Inside a router
initialize: function() {

    this.cached = {
        view: undefined,
        model: undefined
    }
},

index: function(parameter) {
    this.cached.model = this.cached.model || new Model({
        parameter: parameter
    });
    this.cached.view = this.cached.view || new View({
        model: this.cached.model
    });
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a possiblity of saving the whole **state** of my single webpage javascript webpage and not just the model and the view.

So when I press the back button, backbone knows to "return" to a specified state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea! Backbone doesn't have this sort of functionality as standard but you could easily build it yourself using [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js).

The approach would be similar to what you're already doing, however you could save large amounts of your webpage to local storage as a cache.

Particularly if you can use this to cut down on API requests, you could really speed things up.  Just make sure you use a proper cache invalidation mechanism.